Ubuntu Lunar ошибка python3.10-venv : Depends: python-pip-whl (>= 8.1.0-2) but it is not installable при установке пакета
Мой сервер работает под Ubuntu 23.04. При попытке установить пакет nwaf-cabinet, вылетает ошибка python3.10-venv : Depends: python-pip-whl (>= 8.1.0-2) but it is not installable. При установке python3.10-venv ссылается на отсутствие  python-pip-whl. Как я понял  python-pip-whl это сам pip,но он для python3.10 установлен. Python устанавливал из репозиториев deadsnakes.
Мои действия:
-попытка установки nwaf-cabinet
-Установка python3.10 из репозитория deadsnakes
-Установка pip для python3.10
-Установка virtualenv для python3.10 как модуля pip (  python3.10 -m pip install virtualenv )
-Установка python3.10-venv - вылетает ошибка о не установленном пакете python-pip-whl

Ну а aptitude search python-pip-whl чё выдаёт?
